# Creating report and selecting an EmployeeName from database using combobox with duration of date using datepicker

Tags: vb.net

So i have this form where I'll be creating reports, the reports consist of an Employee record. I have put a combobox in the form where i'll be selecting an EmployeeName, the EmployeeName that will be displayed in the combobox is from a column of a child table that consist of jobs he made with a specifiC date. I also put two datepickers that will serve as duration of dates.

How do I execute this, if i select an EmployeeName displayed in the combobox; select a start date(datepicker1) and an end date (datepicker2) and when i hit enter the record of an EmployeeName displayed in the combobox and the dates of his records as I selected on the datepickers will be displayed on the datagridview in the form where I'll be using as a report

The records of an Employee is something like this

```
Employee  - John Doe
Date   -   9/30/19
Job   -   Sewing
ItemCode    - 123123
BundleNumber  - 123123  
Operation - EDGING
Color    -  BLACK
Size - Large
Quantity - 50
```

that should look like a table the first is the column the second is the row but i dont know how to make one here.

Comment: It is very simple, where are you stucked? Just declare for ex. structure "Employee" with associated properties..when hit enter after selecting employee name in combobox and selecting dates, fill the object Employee with desired values (from combobox and datepickers) and then add to datagridview

Comment: You say: "and when i hit enter...". Is that an Enter button that you are clicking on? If so, then just use the "Click" event handler on the Enter button to grab the value of the selectedItem of the combo box when it is triggered.

Comment: It looks very simple, yes. But i really don't know how to do this since im very new to programming. The main problem was i don't know HOW TO EXECUTE the "selecting an EmployeeName from database using combobox with duration of date using datepickers"